# pabbrev-mode idle timer error

Tags: debugging, idle-timer

I have installed again pabbrev and whenever I activate the mode

I constantly get theses 2 errors.

```
Error running timer ‘pabbrev-idle-timer-function’: (invalid-function pabbrev-debug-message)
Error running timer ‘pabbrev-short-idle-timer’: (invalid-function pabbrev-debug-message)
```

I know that `pabbrev-debug-message` is a macro but I cannot debug further than this.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the file was mis-compiled.  More specifically, for some reason, when the file was byte-compiled, Emacs had no knowledge about the `pabbrev-debug-message` macro and hence assumed it must be a function.

How did you install pabbrev?  The 4.2.1 version on GNU ELPA doesn't seem to suffer from such a problem on my end.  I suggest you file a bug-report to the place from which you downloaded it.

Comment: Indeed you are right. The one fromgnu ELPA works fine. I downloaded the one from melpa unstable.  Many thanks